# .word symbol not found in symbol table

Tags: assembly, linked-list, mips, linker-errors

This code was given to me by my professor to use in a program we have to work on but I'm getting this error and am lost on how to fix it.

Code:

```
node9:  .word 9
        .word node10
        .asciiz "nueve"
```

Error: Symbol "Node10" not found in symbol table.

It gives me this error for all nodes
Any help on how to fix this would help a lot, thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`node9:` is a label declaration; it defines a symbol whose address is that position.

But when you use a symbol name somewhere *else* on a line, like as an operand to `.word`, you're making a *reference* to a symbol.

If you reference a symbol but don't define it anywhere with a label, then of course you get a linker error.

Probably you want another declaration like

```
.p2align 2          # make sure the word members are aligned by 2^2 = 4
node10: .word 10
        .word node11
        .asciiz "ten"
```

Obviously at some point you need to have a struct that *doesn't* refer to yet another new label.  e.g. it could point to itself, or it could point back to the first node (circular linked list), or it could have a NULL pointer.

```
.p2align 2
node11: .word 11
        .word 0            # NULL pointer
        .asciiz "eleven"
```

---

BTW, this looks like a linked list with nodes like this in C.

```
struct node { 
    int32_t a;
    struct node *next;
    char buf[];  // flexible array member: arbitrary length buffer, not a pointer
};
```

My asm blocks above are based on this assumption.

So your asm block could be compiler output for something like this at global scope (which would of course give the same linker error):

```
struct node  node9 = {9, node10, "nine" };
```

The `.word` and `.asciiz` directives emit initialized static data into the current section.

Comment: Thank you for this. So essentially .word node10 is a 'pointer' to another label which would make sense why I was getting the error since node10, in this case, doesn't exist. Thanks again!

Comment: @D.Spani: yes, exactly.  `.word node10` is an address as as static initializer, exactly like in C if you wrote (at global scope) `struct node  node9 = {9, node10, "nine" };`